# Duplicated MongoDB collection with smaller document size slower in queries?

Tags: mongodb

Recently been tweaking a collection with a single change, shortening an `atr_list` list property containing all possible attribute combinations to another list - same name - containing each single value, without computing all possible combinations.

From this (simplified): `["attr1=value1", "attr2=value2", "attr1=value1+attr2=value2"]`

To this (simplified): `["attr1=value1", "attr2=value2"]`

The document size has been reduced to more than half of its original size - from 2.5kb to 1kb per MongoDB Document. Indexes have gone down in size too.

**Average response time for a week of data has gone up +5 seconds for the new collection**, having smaller document size and smaller indexes! How is that even possible?

**Is it a matter of how MongoDB arranges documents in memory? Should I remove the old collection and perform a compact in the new one so memory is assigned efficiently?**

Comment: There's really not enough information to assist here and the question may be better for dba.stackexchange.com altogether. We'd need to know things like what queries you execute, what indexes you have, and what your general cluster topology looks like (eg are you using a free Atlas cluster that is subject to throttling?). Even with all that there are many other factors that could be important to your question which may not be discoverable via this type of forum at all

Comment: @user20042973 it's a dedicated k8s cluster with 3 RS, 128GB RAM and 4TB disks. However, in theory without going too much into the details, shouldn't it be faster solely by having smaller documents?

Indexes for both collections are exactly equal, the only changes would be that the list contains less elements.

Comment: Sure, in the most general sense the theory that, all else being the same, smaller documents should have less overhead and therefore potentially provide performance benefits seems plausible at the very least. But of course what you're observing in practice is different than that, therefore there is some discrepancy in our assumptions or configuration. An example: you mention that the _indexes_ are the same. But what about the _queries_ that use those indexes? Are you, for example, searching for items that have multiple attributes? Different queries need different indexes

Comment: @user20042973 same for the queries, that's what bothers me a lot when it comes to those higher average times. Ran an `.explain()` with both approaches and both queries will reach for the same index and apply the same aggregation steps. My main thought would be that RAM is already populated by other collections being constantly updated since this last one is only for testing purposes and it's not receiving updates, so till I do the swap the won't be constatly updated.

Comment: @user20042973 just a did bit more research and the difference may be on the index used. Seems that the old one is pointing to a TTL index based on date, whereas the new one would point the proper one with date + atr_list. Why would it decide to go that route in the old one and somehow being faster?

Comment: I'd really like to help, but without seeing the output from the explains it's basically impossible for me to do anything but speculate. Again I don't even know which query (or what) is 'pointing' to one index vs the other. Make sure you've got `"allPlansExecution"` mode for the same query values then upload them somewhere (a gist, pastebin, whatever) and share the link(s). Plan selection is an entire topic by itself which needs artifacts (like explain plans) to reason about. That should also give us an indication of whether or not that's the problem or unrelated.